# Check if value IS NULL on specific row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which is finding the count where:

stage_2 IS NULL
stage_1 is equal to 1
member_group is 5
grouped by rel_id

Where there is at least 2 rows that meet the above.

This works fine. It outputs the correct result of 6. (in my fiddle).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_result
FROM (
    SELECT sub.entry_id
    FROM exp_judging AS jud
    INNER JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
    WHERE jud.stage_2 IS NULL
    AND jud.stage_1 = 1 
    AND sub.member_group = 5
    GROUP BY jud.rel_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) AS a
```

The issue is that if one of the judge rows has entered a score in 'stage_2' it continues to count this rel_id as there are still more than 2 rows that have NULL in stage_2.

What I want to do, is check that all that the above is true, BUT also, that the row with judge_id '14' has NULL for stage_2.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a SQL Fiddle with my table and current query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ee5/1

Comment: Note that enumerated column names are very often symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: Please see the amended data in the new sql fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an intermediate result as follows...

```
  SELECT s.id
      , s.member_group
      , j.judge_id
      , j.stage_1
      , j.stage_2
   FROM exp_judging j
   JOIN exp_submissions s
     ON s.id = j.rel_id
    AND j.stage_1 = 1
    AND s.member_group = 5
  ORDER
     BY j.rel_id
      , j.judge_id;

 +----+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
 | id | member_group | judge_id | stage_1 | stage_2 |
 +----+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
 | 70 |            5 |       14 |       1 |       5 |<-- exclude because [14,5]
 | 70 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |<-- exclude because of [14,5] above
 | 73 |            5 |       14 |       1 |       5 |<-- exclude because [14,5]
 | 73 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |<-- exclude because [14,5] above
 | 73 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |<-- exclude because [14,5] above
 | 75 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 75 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 77 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 77 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 78 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 79 |            5 |       14 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 80 |            5 |       14 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 80 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 80 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 81 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 83 |            5 |       14 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 83 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 +----+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

To exclude the rows highlighted, we can do this...

```
  SELECT s.id
      , s.member_group
      , j.judge_id
      , j.stage_1
      , j.stage_2
   FROM exp_judging j
   JOIN exp_judging x
     ON x.rel_id = j.rel_id
    AND x.judge_id = 14
    AND x.stage_2 IS NULL
   JOIN exp_submissions s
     ON s.id = j.rel_id
    AND j.stage_1 = 1
    AND s.member_group = 5
  GROUP
     BY j.rel_id
      , j.judge_id;

 +----+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
 | id | member_group | judge_id | stage_1 | stage_2 |
 +----+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
 | 75 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 75 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 77 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 77 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 78 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 79 |            5 |       14 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 80 |            5 |       14 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 80 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 80 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 81 |            5 |       16 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 83 |            5 |       14 |       1 |    NULL |
 | 83 |            5 |       15 |       1 |    NULL |
 +----+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

From here, the remaining steps are trivial...

```
 SELECT s.id
      , COUNT(*)
   FROM exp_judging j
   JOIN exp_judging x
     ON x.rel_id = j.rel_id
    AND x.judge_id = 14
    AND x.stage_2 IS NULL
   JOIN exp_submissions s
     ON s.id = j.rel_id
    AND j.stage_1 = 1
    AND s.member_group = 5
  GROUP
     BY j.rel_id;

+----+----------+
| id | COUNT(*) |
+----+----------+
| 75 |        2 |
| 77 |        2 |
| 78 |        1 |
| 79 |        1 |
| 80 |        3 |
| 81 |        1 |
| 83 |        2 |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think its what I am trying to achieve. I have edited my question to hopefully explain a bit clearer, so I would be grateful if you could take another look and see if thats possible?

Comment: id 75, 77, 80 and 83 should be the only rows returned, with a count of 4 when the judge_id is 14, as id 70 and 73 are not NULL. Id 78 and 79 should not be showing at all. See my current query to see this.

Comment: In that case, the solution I offered before would appear to be pretty much what you're after.

Comment: As far as I could tell when I went through your previous answer, it was returning results that didn't have 2 or more rows with stage_1 = 1. Can you repost your previous answer, or an amendement, as I was unable to find a way to correct it.

Comment: Thank you, but 78, 79 and 81 should not be showing at all, as they don't have 2 or more rows with stage_1 = 1.

Comment: I am very new to SQL. I tried to solve the original query you answered with, but everything I tried failed, so I am in the situation unless I am shown how, I wont know to future times.

Comment: I suggest you take another look at your original solution. There's a clue there.